# Ubuntu hostname configuration

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have set up all the necessary configurations to set up a static host besides localhost (default) on Ubuntu, but I can ping the host I set with the /etc/host file but I cant use nslookup or the host command to resolve it. By the way I have checked resolve.conf files and nsswitch.conf . It says NXdomain. Any advice?

Comment: This question is off topic for SO. Try asking it on [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I agree.  Someone who is familiar with Ubuntu can determine the correct answer.  If adding/editing the hostname entry in /etc/sysconfig/network works in Ubuntu, this should be a *nix question.  If Ubuntu does it differently, then it should go there.

Comment: @sravnv - as the answers & comments say, you need DNS for `nslookup` and/or `host` resolution. Any particular reason you would need DNS resolution to work on your host for your host?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nslookup or host command to resolve your hostname, you would need to setup a local dns server because by default Ubuntu wont use the gethost command to resolve the info from host files, therefore external applications that require host name resolve or sockets wont e able to find your static host. Like  i said set up a local DNS server, its quite easy and straight forward.
Use this Link:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04
Good luck!

Comment: Hostname resolution goes 1. cache, 2. hosts file, 3. DNS.  Any system call for name resolution goes through these steps.  Setting up a DNS server may seem simple and straightforward, but doing so dramatically increases your attack surface, and hardening DNS is not easy.

Comment: @Xalorous - nslookup asks DNS. So without a valid DNS record there will be no nslookup different from NXDomain. As for the hostname resolution you are right (while it was possible to change the order - see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172218)), but the OP asked why nslookup does not resolve. The same for the host command, it performs a DNS lookup so will NEVER return anything from the hosts file.